# how to replace AsyncTask by RxAndroid

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to use RxAndroid to do the same work which is AsyncTask exactly does. I coded a simple example, where I enter a n integer in an edittext and when I press
a button, I make the hread to sleep for 3 seconds using "SystemClock.sleep" and while the thread is sleeping I show a progressbar and when the three seconds 
elapsed the progresssbar will adisappear and the value entered in the edittext will be multiplied by 10 and displayed in atextview.

normally, when I use AsyncTask, I show the progressbar in onPreExecute and make it to disappear in onPostExecute. but when I run the below code I  receive the 
following error:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

how to handle it properly in RxAndroid?

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private EditText mEditTextValueToProcess = null;
private Button mButtonGoAsynchronous = null;
private TextView mTextViewProcessedValue = null;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;
private rx.Observable<String> mAsyncObservable = null;

Subscriber mAsyncSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCompleted");
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String o) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onNext:->after processing " + o);
        mTextViewProcessedValue.setText(o);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intiViews();

    mAsyncObservable = rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            subscriber.onNext("" + Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValueToProcess.getText().toString()) * 10);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });

}

private void intiViews() {
    mEditTextValueToProcess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    mButtonGoAsynchronous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go_asynchronous);
    mTextViewProcessedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_processed_value);
    //mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);

    mButtonGoAsynchronous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAsyncObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(mAsyncSubscriber);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Rx-java2 Tag while using only Rxjava1? :)

Comment: override onStart inside mAsyncSubscriber and make your progressbar visible there. Because as you are doing `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, code inside observable will be executed on another thread then ur UI thread

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
private Observable<String> createObservable(final int number) { 
     return rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            subscriber.onNext("" + number  * 10);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}

private void intiViews() {
    mEditTextValueToProcess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    mButtonGoAsynchronous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go_asynchronous);
    mTextViewProcessedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_processed_value);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);

    mButtonGoAsynchronous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            createObservable(Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValueToProcess.getText().toString()))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnNext((ignored) -> {
                         mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    })
                    .subscribe(mAsyncSubscriber);
        }
    });
}
```

?

Comment: i liked the code style you posted..but would you please let me know what does (ignored)-> mean??

Comment: It's a lambda expression, supported by adding either Retrolambda or updating to android studio 3.0.0

Comment: It's an input parameter that's not relevant for calling that method

Answer (score 1):

You need to change few things to achieve this. Look at `mAsyncSubscriber` initialization, onStart() method & progressBar initialization. The reason why you are getting the error is you are initializing & making your progressbar visible in another thread then your UI thread (because you specified this -> `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()`).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private EditText mEditTextValueToProcess = null;
private Button mButtonGoAsynchronous = null;
private TextView mTextViewProcessedValue = null;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;
private rx.Observable<String> mAsyncObservable = null;
Subscriber mAsyncSubscriber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intiViews();

   mAsyncSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {

   // Override onStart method
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCompleted");
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String o) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onNext:->after processing " + o);
        mTextViewProcessedValue.setText(o);
    }
};


    mAsyncObservable = rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            subscriber.onNext("" + Integer.valueOf(mEditTextValueToProcess.getText().toString()) * 10);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });

}

private void intiViews() {
    // Init your progressbar
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
    mEditTextValueToProcess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    mButtonGoAsynchronous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go_asynchronous);
    mTextViewProcessedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_processed_value);
    //mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);

    mButtonGoAsynchronous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAsyncObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(mAsyncSubscriber);
        }
    });
}
```